# NServiceBus 3.0 MarkAsComplete() causes NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException

Tags: nservicebus

I have upgraded some NSB 2.6 endpoints to use NSB 3.0 and now have them working for the most part. In one of my handlers in a saga I update a repo, and then MarkAsComplete(). In the logfile I see the following error;

2012-03-11 16:45:47,667 [Worker.14] WARN  NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus - MyHandlerABC failed handling message.
NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException: Exception of type 'NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException' was thrown.
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.Msmq.MsmqMessageSender.NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.ISendMessages.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.ClearTimeoutsFor(Guid sagaId)
   at NServiceBus.Sagas.Impl.SagaDispatcherFactory.NotifyTimeoutManagerThatSagaHasCompleted(ISaga saga)
   at NServiceBus.Sagas.Impl.SagaDispatcherFactory.<>c_*DisplayClass6.b*_1()
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.<>c_*DisplayClass20.b*_1d(Action dispatch)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.DispatchMessageToHandlersBasedOnType(IBuilder builder, Object toHandle)
2012-03-11 16:45:47,668 [Worker.14] WARN  NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport - Failed raising 'transport message received' event for message with ID=c2bf13f9-7138-4df5-aa42-9cc3f9817e78\13152
NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportMessageHandlingFailedException: Exception of type 'NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportMessageHandlingFailedException' was thrown.
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.DispatchMessageToHandlersBasedOnType(IBuilder builder, Object toHandle)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleMessage(IBuilder builder, TransportMessage m)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleTransportMessage(IBuilder childBuilder, TransportMessage msg)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender, TransportMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg)

That occurs after NSB has finished handling a message (I have logging as the last line in the handler, and that appears immediately above the stack trace above)

These endpoints were working before upgrading to NSB3.0 so I'm sure I'm missing some config setting somewhere. Is there something new required to get sagas working in NSB3.0?

Comment: I've added a MarkAsComplete() method call into another handler and tried that, and that's also blowing up. So, what queue is NSB trying to contact? ('NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException')

Comment: I've commented out any MarkAsComplete() lines for the time being to get this working again

Answer (score 2):

When you complete a saga the timeout manager is automatically notified so that it can clear any outstanding timeouts for that saga instance.

```
public void ClearTimeoutsFor(Guid sagaId)
{
        var controlMessage = ControlMessage.Create();

        controlMessage.Headers[Headers.SagaId] = sagaId.ToString();
        controlMessage.Headers[Headers.ClearTimeouts] = true.ToString();

        MessageSender.Send(controlMessage, TimeoutManagerAddress);
}
```

Can you verify that you have a queue called `{endpointname}`. Timeouts on your machine?

Comment: This should be it - thanks Andreas! I'll try this later when I get home. I hadn't created those additional timeout queues

Answer (score 0):

In 3.0, you have to name your endpoints or else the endpoint name will default to the namespace of your IConfigureThisEndpoint implementation.  My guess is that the queue name you were using does not match the name of the destination endpoint and if you let the endpoint create the queues, the queue name has changed.  Hope this helps.